# how to edit a bilingual text by scripting?

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I have a column of words in which English words are glued to Chinese words like this:

> abominate********
>
> abhor*************

(The stars represent the Chinese alphabet)

I want to write a script to separate the English words and put it in another file. Is sth like this possible by script writing?

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

sure, since english words use the latin alphabet and chinese words don't, just strip the end of the line starting at the first non-latin symbol.

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z ].*//' < source-file >  result-file
```

Comment: It removes the English words after the first chinese character, too.

Comment: the example has none such

Answer (score 0):

Simple remove every character which isn't space, tab, or an english character:

```
sed 's/[^a-zA-Z ]//g' <source >result
```

Beware to use a unicode-compliant mode.

You can make further post-processing, too, for example a

```
for i in $(cat result);do echo "$i";done|sort|uniq
```

will order `result` alphabetically and removes the duplicates ("the", "a" and "for" will happen in this text probably very many times, you need probably only one from them).

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -Po '[\x00-\x77]+'  source > justEN.txt
```